# How to change state of just one user in the list?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I have a list of users loged in my application and they can have three states: info, success and help and made three buttons beside every user so they can change their status when they click on of those buttons. When user click on a specific button I want to change class of that button but I'm stuck here because when I click on some button of some user he changes state of user who has been logged first in the application (first user in my list).

Here is my html:

```
    <ul class="list-unstyled" style="color:white; font-size:20px;
    margin-top:-10px; margin-left:-14.5px">
        <li style="padding: 15px 0px 15px 30px; border-bottom:solid #0A2A0A;
        margin-right:-14.5px" ng-repeat="user in users">
            {{user.username}}
            <span style="padding-right:15px"></span>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-md" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <button id="info" type="button" class="btn btn-info" 
                ng-click="info(user.username)">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                </button>
                <button id="success" type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                ng-click="success(user.username)">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                </button>
                <button id="help" type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                ng-click="help(user.username)">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and here is controller for that html:

```
    taskApp.controller('TaskNumController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams){
        $scope.tasks = $route.current.locals.task;
        $scope.users = $route.current.locals.users;

        $scope.success = function(name){
            $('#info').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default');
            $('#success').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success');
            $('#help').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-default');
        };
        $scope.help = function(name){
            $('#info').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default');
            $('#success').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
            $('#help').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-danger');
        };
        $scope.info = function(name){
            $('#info').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-info');
            $('#success').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
            $('#help').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-default');
        };
    });
```

taskApp is the name of my module.

Can anyone help me? I would be very thankful :)

Comment: You need to be using `ngClass` instead of manually manipulating the DOM. DOM manipulation should never be done inside of a Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in this case is to utilize the ng-class attribute on your elements and not handle style changes in the controller.

**Controller**

```
taskApp.controller('TaskNumController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams){
        $scope.tasks = $route.current.locals.task;
        $scope.users = $route.current.locals.users;
        $scope.setUserStatus = function(user, status){
           user.status = status;
        }
    });
```

**View**

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-md" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <button id="info" type="button" class="btn" 
                ng-click="setUserStatus(user, 'info')" ng-class="{'btn-info': user.status === 'info', 'btn-default': user.status !== 'info' }">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                </button>
                <button id="success" type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                ng-click="setUserStatus(user, 'success')" ng-class="{'btn-success': user.status === 'success', 'btn-default': user.status !== 'success' }">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                </button>
                <button id="help" type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                ng-click="setUserStatus(user, 'help')" ng-class="{'btn-danger': user.status === 'help', 'btn-default': user.status !== 'help' }">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
```

This means you will have to maintain a status for each user, but that shouldn't be too big of a deal. Alternatively, you could just set the status in the ng-click as well (ng-click="user.status = 'info';") instead of calling a function, but I think it feels a little cleaner if the controller actually handles that.